# Clear all cookies in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I'm working on a Asp.net Core website , and in my logout link I want to remove all current domain cookies.
when I was work with Asp.net MVC I tried this code

```
string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
foreach (string cookie in myCookies)
{
  Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
}
```

this code doesn't work in Asp.net Core.
How can I clear all cookies in Asp.net Core?

Comment: try use `Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);`

Comment: I find this code _secureCookies.Remove(HttpContext, "UserName");
but i want clear all Cookiies

Comment: how can i use __secureCookies.Remove(); in foreach and find all of cookies?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`Request.Cookies` is a key-value collection where the Key is a cookie name. So

```
foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
}
```

See:

```
public abstract class HttpRequest
{
    // Summary:
    //     /// Gets the collection of Cookies for this request. ///
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The collection of Cookies for this request.
    public abstract IRequestCookieCollection Cookies { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

and [IRequestCookieCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.irequestcookiecollection) is

```
public interface IRequestCookieCollection : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, IEnumerable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//ASP.NET Core
foreach (string cookie in myCookies)
{
  Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);  
}
```